# JAVA - Finding shortest path between 2 vertex using Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: java

So I am doing a math project, not a computer science one, but I want to use code to help collect my data. To this I want to use Dijkstra's Algorithm and count how many edges it has to go to before it can get an answer. However I cannot find any pre existing code that works for my graph.

```
package mathematicsia;

import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>
{
    public final String name;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;
    public Vertex(String argName) { name = argName; }
    public String toString() { return name; }
    public int compareTo(Vertex other)
    {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

}


class Edge
{
    public final Vertex target;
    public final double weight;
    public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight)
    { target = argTarget; weight = argWeight; }
}

public class DijkstrasAlgorithm
{
    public static void computePaths(Vertex source)
    {
        source.minDistance = 0.;
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
        vertexQueue.add(source);

        while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

            // Visit each edge exiting u
            for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
            {
                Vertex v = e.target;
                double weight = e.weight;
                double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
                if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
                    vertexQueue.remove(v);

                    v.minDistance = distanceThroughU ;
                    v.previous = u;
                    vertexQueue.add(v);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target)
    {
        List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
            path.add(vertex);

        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // mark all the vertices 
        Vertex P = new Vertex("P");
        Vertex L = new Vertex("L");
        Vertex E = new Vertex("E");

        Vertex B4 = new Vertex("B4"); //Bridge Level 4
        Vertex B5 = new Vertex("B5"); //Bridge Level 5

        Vertex A2 = new Vertex("A2"); //Stairs A
        Vertex A3 = new Vertex("A3");
        Vertex A4 = new Vertex("A4");
        Vertex A5 = new Vertex("A5");
        Vertex A6 = new Vertex("A6");

        Vertex C2 = new Vertex("C2"); //Stairs C
        Vertex C3 = new Vertex("C3");
        Vertex C4 = new Vertex("C4");
        Vertex C5 = new Vertex("C5");
        Vertex C6 = new Vertex("C6");

        // set the edges and weight
        L.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A2, 83) }; //A
        L.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(B4, 90) }; //B
        L.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(B5, 130) }; //C
        L.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C2,86 ) }; //D

        B4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C4, 33) }; //E
        B4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A4,59 ) }; //F

        A2.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C2, 97) }; //G
        A3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C3,70 ) }; //H
        A4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C4,71 ) }; //I

        A2.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A3,15 ) }; //J
        A3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A4,15 ) }; //K
        A4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A5,15 ) }; //L
        A5.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A6, 15) }; //M
        A6.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C6, 75) }; //N

        P.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A6, 27) }; //O
        E.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A3,85 ) }; //P
        P.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C6, 97) }; //Q
        E.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C3, 25) }; //R

        B5.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C5,33 ) }; //S
        B5.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A5, 59) }; //T

        C5.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C4, 15) }; //U
        C4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C3, 15) }; //V
        C3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C2,24 ) }; //W
        C6.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C5, 15) }; //X

        P.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C6,73 ) }; //Y 
        A5.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C5, 75) }; //Z



        computePaths(L); // run Dijkstra
        System.out.println("Distance to " + P + ": " + P.minDistance);
        List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(P);
        System.out.println("Path: " + path);
    }
}
```

This does not work as it gives me an error when I try running, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with your Vertex class. You have a non-optimal design of storing both the topographical information:

- name
- adjacencies

And mutable information about some traversal:

- minDistance
- previous

Lets start by "pureifying" your Vertex to only represent the topographical information. In additional lets implement hashCode() and equals() so we can use it in a dictionary.

```
class Vertex
{
    public final String name;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;

    public Vertex(String argName) { name = argName; }
    public String toString() { return name; }
    public int equals(Vertex other) {
        return this.name.compareTo(other.name);
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Then lets make a result class to hold the path set:

```
class Path {
    HashMap<Vertex, Integer> distances = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Vertex, Vertex> backtrack = new HashMap<>(); 
}
```

Now, we can implement Dijkstras. I modified your implementation a little bit so that it functionally matches the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). That way you can follow along with their animations.

```
public Path computePaths(Vertex source)
{
    Path p = new Path();
    Set<Vertex> visited = new HashSet<>();
    distances.put(source, 0); // Distance from source to source

    Queue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
    vertexQueue.add(source);
    visited.add(source);

    while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex u = vertexQueue.remove();

        // Visit each edge exiting u
        for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
        {
            Vertex v = e.target;
            double distanceThroughU = p.distances.get(u) + e.weight;
            if (!p.distances.contains(v) || distanceThroughU < p.distances.get(v)) {
                p.distances.put(v, distance);
                p.backtrack.put(v, u);
            }
            // We didn't prime the queue but we need to make sure we visit everyone
            // at least once.
            if (!visited.contains(v)) {
                vertexQueue.add(v);
                visited.add(v);
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

Finally, we can use that Path to create paths:

```
public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Path p, Vertex target)
{
    List<Vertex> path = new List<Vertex>();
      for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = p.backtrack.get(vertex))
        path.add(vertex);

    Collections.reverse(path);
    return path;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I am having trouble implementing it. Like where does my Edges and Vertices go from the previous version.